# PHP & XML, What Is Recommended?

Tags: php, xml

Background:
So i'm writing a web-service style web application as a way to increase my knowledge of how PHP and XML work together. I want to eventually take that XML data and use it in a mobile phone application but that's a different issue. I can connect to the data, pull, and process all the information with PHP and I've managed to get it exporting to CSV. I want to now begin to push that data out in XML.

Question:
What is the (a) recommended way to work with XML in PHP?

References:
[PHP Manual, XML Portion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php)

Comment: I like [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: Yep, SimpleXML gets stuff done. Here's another SO Q you might get some info from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892313/alternatives-to-simplexml-for-parsing-xml-files-with-php, also, depending on where your PHP/XML goes from there XSLT can be very handy.

Comment: Me too, I almost always use SimpleXML, but you can check out the PEAR libraries: [link](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=22&catname=XML)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php)

Comment: And since you said Webservices, you might want to extend your question to include http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php

Comment: Depending on your requirements, I'd suggest taking a look at [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) since it's far easier to work with than XML in just about every language...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [simple XML](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which is way easier to handle xml operations.

Comment: That depends on the XML to be handled. Just because it's called SimpleXml doesnt mean it is the simplest for handling XML.

Comment: In fact, I typically find SimpleXML harder to use than Dom.  Sure, it's less verbose, but it's also less explicit and requires intimate knowledge of the behaviors to follow.  I'd suggest DomDocument instead...

Comment: As I said: I suggest. I've tried several ways work with xml and I found simpleXML very convenient.